# Bootstrap multiple carousels on one page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm after 3 carousels on the one page that are controlled by the one control.
So when clicking next or previous all carousels move at once.

This an example with 3 carousels but there all seperate.

I'm stuck.

Comment: Any code would be great. I'm sure your problem is there :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/1247/

The key part of the code to control all carousels is this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-slide="prev" href=".carousel">Prev All</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-slide="next" href=".carousel">Next All</button>
```

By specifying the .carousel class rather than a specific ID, the button triggers events on all carousels on the page.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Thank you so much:)